# How can GDALWARP output ISEA (Icosahedral Snyder Equal Area) projection raster?

Tags: command-line, raster, gdal, map-projections

Produce ISEA "Icosahedral Snyder Equal Area" GEOTIFF/raster with gdalwarp.
Is an icosahedral projection impossible to produce with PROJ/GDAL ?

[image: desired output from gdalwarp]
Produce ISEA "Icosahedral Snyder Equal Area" GEOTIFF/raster with gdalwarp.
I am trying to use gdal tools to convert Plate-Carree to ISEA and back.

The input GEOTIFF is " NE1_50M_SR_W.tif " 
directly from  "The Natural Earth quick start kit" at [Natural Earth Downloads](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/).

I can find no input format or argument permutation that satasfies this error message.

```
gdalwarp  -te -180 -90 +180 +90     -t_srs "+proj=isea +elipse=sphere" NE1_50M_SR_W.tif out-isea.tif
ERROR 1: Too many points (10201 out of 10201) failed to transform, unable to compute output bounds.

gdalinfo NE1_50M_SR_W.tif 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: NE1_50M_SR_W.tif
Size is 10800, 5400
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-179.999999999999972,90.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.033333333333330,-0.033333333333330)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_DATETIME=2014:10:18 09:32:38
  TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT=2 (pixels/inch)
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=Adobe Photoshop CC 2014 (Macintosh)
  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=342.85699
  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=342.85699
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"W, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Upper Right ( 180.0000000,  90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right ( 180.0000000, -90.0000000) (180d 0' 0.00"E, 90d 0' 0.00"S)
Center      (  -0.0000000,   0.0000000) (  0d 0' 0.00"W,  0d 0' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=10800x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=10800x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=10800x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
molly@morfydd:~/Documents/earthgeo/gdal/scripttest$
```

Comment: Thank you @shellter, the project is complex, and so composing the question concisely and briefly is a challenge. For an example of a similar project see my online JS reprojector here:   https://morfyddjames.github.io/platecarree.html

Comment: Did you figure this out on your own? If so, post your answer so I can award the bounty to you. Did you look for a dev forum specifically for this tool (or developer organization)? Maybe they can help, or add it as a new feature. Good luck.

Comment: Hello @shelter, I contacted the GDAL developers at github to report the error, and they clarified that GDAL cannot reproject rasters unless the PROJ library supports both Forward and Inverse on any particular projection. ISEA has no PROJ inverse so is not capable of raster output. They have amended the error text in the new version to reflect this. The bot here keeps deleting this answer when I try to post it as such.

Comment: Sorry for that. I guess the bot will get your 50 points. Feel free to raise a stink (on meta.stackoverflow.com I guess) if you would like the points, I will back you up, but not take the lead. Or may you can try flagging this for moderator intervention, or at least they could explain the rules. Hope you can find another solution. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you @shelter, My only concern is improving the understanding and skill levels of coders. I'm happy that the error has been addressed by the developers, and will be clarified in the documentation.  I have no idea what points and bounties are, or what they're meant to do. (please don't explain it to me ; )

Comment: Please help de main implementation, PROJ libary, to prioritize the implementation of the ISEA projection, https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/issues/3047